# Typescript compiler itself supports static check, Why anotherTSlint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm new to the typescript world and would like to find out

---

since typescript compiler **tsc.cmd** already handle all the static analysis/check job which Typescript features , so why do we also need another **TSlint**? Are part of their function overlapping or any compelling reason? thanks.

Comment: tslint manages a bunch of rules that has only aesthetics purpose, eg: code indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Linting tools like **TSLint** allow developers to discover problems with their code without executing it.

The built in compiler of Typescript will discover problems only when you transpile(compile) the code.

**TSLint** instead will alert you while you're typing, which is much faster as you do not have to wait until the Typescript compiler reaches the point in code where the error is located.